# Model won't render

Tags: rendering, camera

Not sure what's going wrong here, but for some reason I can't render my character; I just get a blank image plane. I don't believe my camera and scene settings have been changed, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I even tried adding a new camera, but that didn't work either. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an image in video sequencer:

[image]

Remove it, or turn render from Sequencer off

Comment: Bingo. That's done it. Must have been from my previous render before I altered the model. Thank you. :D

Comment: Other problem now is that my renders are dark as though there's no light. The layer with my light is selected and it's enabled in the outliner.

Comment: @DustyShinigami please, ask one question per tread.

Comment: Solved my same problem!